# Single word for treating someone harshly, inconsiderately, negligently?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am sure there is such a word. Think of it as combining elements of harsh, uncaring, inconsiderate treatment with neglect and indifference.

For example, a parent that forces a child to do some particular activity they don't enjoy, harshly overruling their objections and indifferent to how it makes the child feel (and yes "abuse" is too extreme).

The word would fit sentences like:

She was treated [WORD].

She was left downtrodden after being treated [WORD] for so long.

I am looking for words more specific than words like "miserably" or "poorly" - the word would *almost* be synonymous with "roughly", "harshly", but with greater connotations of neglect and indifference. I am sure the word is out there but it escapes me (and I have consulted a thesaurus!)

Comment: She was treated *abusively*.

Comment: @HotLicks: OP said he thought "abusive" too extreme. Though I am having trouble imagining a spectrum _between_ abusive and harsh. Josh suggests brutally, but again, is there any room in between? There is probably a Dickens character who can be made a metonym for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word your looking for is *Callously*, an adverb of *Callous*.

Callous is defined as: Feeling or showing no sympathy for others:  hard-hearted - callous indifference to suffering.

> She was treated *callously*.
>
> She was left downtrodden after being treated *callously* for so long.

Comment: This indeed was the word I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about *contemptuous*?

> contempt
> noun
>
> the feeling with which a person regards anything considered mean, vile, or worthless; disdain; scorn.
>
> the state of being despised; dishonor; disgrace.

Answer (score 0):

I may have used something similar to brushoff or cold shoulder with appropriate verbiage

Answer (score 0):

She was treated ***[brutally](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/brutally)***:

> - In a  extremely ruthless or cruel way.
> - In a  crude or unfeeling manner or speech. (AHD)

Answer (score 0):

We can modify a verb with an adverb (I like "callously" above). We can also choose a verb to stand on its own. So I think you might simply use "mistreated"?